# Open other URL in <body> using hash # without leave URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have two HTML file, **`index.html`** and **`about.html`**.
I wanna open my **`about.html`** in my **`index.html`** without leave my **`index.html`**.

If I see, most website using **`#about`**, so they can load **`about.html`** in their **`index.html`** with replacing maybe some div in their **`index`** to **`about.html`**.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Google for AJAX load page into index page and take a look at the History API as epascarello suggested. PushState, popState etc...

Comment: A quick Google Search about `Routing on Single Page Application` should bring up sufficient amount of resources to get started with.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure this is what you want to do but if you want to display the about.html page somewhere in the index page there is something in HTML called iframe:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

But if you want something more dynamically you should look into AJAX and stuff like that as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using simple Ajax requests with pure javascript. I wrote a function which gets a url-hash like `#about` and loads `about.html` then put the whole content into `.container` element of the index page:

```
// Container of external page contents   
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

var loadWebpage = function (which) {
    which = which.slice(1);
    if (!which) return container.innerHTML = '';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', which + '.html');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) container.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        else console.log(which + ' page not found!')
    };
    xhr.send()
};

window.onhashchange = function () {
    loadWebpage(location.hash) // When hash changes load that page
};

loadWebpage(location.hash); // When page opens load current hash page
```

I hope that it helps, Good luck